# conditional inputs do not get affected by jquery plugin meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a meteorjs application in which we have a form and some inputs get rendered based on the values of the session variable which is set on the change of another input we have applied a jquery plugin to the form that manipulates the inputs of the form but the plugin does not affect on the dynamically rendered input controls.If anybody has any idea please help me.

The problem is as follows:

there is a service select box and when user changes the values of the service we will set a session variable true and in the template if this session variable is true we will show another select for sub category and we have already applied the plugin on the form with onrendred but the plugin works for the services salect but does not affect sub category select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor JS Template rendered function called before template is rendered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352059/meteor-js-template-rendered-function-called-before-template-is-rendered)