# Event after template helper returns result

Tags: meteor

I have "Items" collection, each instance has "title" and "price" attribute.

Template HTML:

```html
<template name="home">
    <div>
        <h1>Items</h1>
        {{#each items}}
            <p data-price="{{price}}">{{text}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Template helpers:

```js
Template.home.helpers({
    items: function() {
        return Items.find();
    }
});
```

For example I want to loop over each "p" tag and get "data-price" attribute value.
Where do I put this code. I tried to use template "rendered" event, but that does not work.
Well that makes sense, when template "rendered" event fired, it does not mean that items helper already returned collection.

So this will return empty array:

```js
Template.home.rendered = function() {
    var items = template.findAll('p');
    console.log(items);
}
```

And this will work as needed:

```js
Template.home.rendered = function() {
    var template = this;

    // wait for 1 second, and then try to loop over "p"
    setTimeout(function() {
        var items = template.findAll('p');
        console.log(items);
    }, 1000);
};
```

So how can I run code after items helper finishes getting data? Maybe there are some callback for that?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352059/meteor-js-template-rendered-function-called-before-template-is-rendered). However, unless you are using a plugin that needs it, you should never need to use `data` attributes in your elements in meteor since each element has a context. I'd recommend reading [this post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/).

Comment: Yes, using data attribute was a total nonsense.

Comment: Well my idea was to kinda sum prices. But maybe this logic will look better in helper itself. I'm trying to invent a wheel :)

Comment: Yeah I could give more specific direction if I knew exactly what you wanted, but it sounds like a problem that is better suited towards `helpers` rather than `rendered`.

Comment: When you subscribe items try attachich subscribe to some variable(var temp = Meteor.subscribe~), and wait for temp.ready() - this will return true when whole collection is ready, therefore DOM elements